# Multiple If else constraints in Mixed integer programming

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, python, constraint-programming

How to formulate the following as constraints in MILP?

a[0][0] = y, if x[0]= 0,

a[0][0] = 0, if x[0] != 0,
.
.

.
.

a[i][j] = b[i][j-1] + y, if x[j]=i,

a[i][j] = a[i][j-1],  if x[j] != i,
...
.
.
.

b[0][0] = z[0], if x[0] =0,

b[0][0] = 0, if x[0] != 0,
.
.
.
.
.

b[i][j] = b[i][j-1] + z[i], if x[j] = i,

b[i][j] = b[i][j-1], if x[j] != i,
.....

Suggest answers based on optimization or coding , both will help.
How to use Piece-wise constraint or logical based constraint for this MILP?

Comment: a, b, y, z are continuous variables (float) And x will be  an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just seem to have hidden a long list of constraints of the form $(x_i=j)  \Rightarrow \text{equalities}_{ij}$

Introduce a binary matrix $C_{ij}$ with $\sum_j C_{ij}= 1$ and $C_{ij} \Rightarrow \{x_{i} = j, \text{equalities}_{ij}\}$

To model the binary implication you can use big-M modelling, e.g. $-M(1- C_{ij})\leq x_{i} - j\leq M (1-C_{ij})$ and similar for all the other equalities.

The big-M model for $x_i$ can be replaced with $x_i=\sum_j C_{ij} j$ to reduce the model slightly.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that.

Comment: Nothing forces $C$ to be nonzero. You need to impose $\sum_j C_{ij}=1$ for all $i$. Also, the big-M constraints should instead have $M(1-C_{ij})$.

Comment: Absolutely, fixed.

Comment: solved it, thank you